# Java swing bug with custom button

Tags: java, image, swing, jar, jbutton

Having problems creating a custom JButton that is an Image. I had everything working with a normal JButton (like in the comment on the 2nd line) this way I wouldn't have to get an InputStream and start the button has an icon.
The trouble I'm having is that when I pressed the replay button (to play again) the window closes and only one window should pop out (as it happens with a "normal" JButton) but in this case 4-5 windows reopen and I don't know why.

I started thinking it was because the time to get an `InputStream` and doing `ImageIO.read()` the game would start and see that the variable running was false and then started reopening windows until it's true but I can't see how to verify that.

**Note:** I have functions that on ActionPerformed verify if the snake has collided and if so `running = false` and `GameOver()` will be called

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener { 
    JButton replay; //= new JButton("Play Again"); 
    GamePanel() {
        ...
        try {
            InputStream is_replay = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Snake/lib/img/playagain.png");
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(is_replay));
            replay = new JButton(icon);
            replay.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            replay.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            ...
        } catch (IOException|FontFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.add(replay);
        replay.setVisible(false);
        replay.setBounds(SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - 100, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 200, 200, 100);
        ...
        startGame();
    }

    public void startGame() {
        spawnApple();
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
        ...

        replay.setVisible(true);
        replay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == replay) {
                    JComponent comp = (JComponent)e.getSource();
                    Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp);
                    win.dispose();  //It will close the current window
                    new GameFrame();  //It will create a new game
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
    GameFrame() {
        JPanel panel = new GamePanel();
        this.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);  //Needed to add components
        this.setTitle("Snake Game");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();  //Fit JFrame to the components
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}

public class SnakeGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new GameFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: An [mre] code post would be much more helpful to us (and correspondingly to you) than either the full program (too big) or non-compilable/non-runnable code snippets (which you are now posting). Please consider creating and posting one in your question. Side note that is usually better to re-set your current GUI to its initial state rather than create and display a new GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"in this case 4-5 windows reopen"*

This suggests that you are probably adding multiple ActionListeners to the replay JButton.  A new listener is added each time game over method is called, and this is incorrect. I would not add the ActionListener to the button in the game over method but rather add it *once* where you create the replay button.

Comment: That solves my issue! But I'm still not to sure why this happens

Comment: @AndréClérigo: again, it is because the listener gets added to the button multiple times. I have no idea how often `gameOver()` is called -- only you know that since only you have the running code, but again, each time it is called, a new listener is added, and that is not going to work well.